# Express routing pass variable to required file

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes, request

I'm trying to have all my controllers called in a file called index, so I don't just build all express routes in one file.

Therefore my index.js looks like:

```
//imports and stuff
router.use('/auth', require('./auth'))
router.use('/users', require('./users'))
router.use('/:world_id/villages', require('./villages'))
//export router
```

Then i have the auth.js and users.js files.

auth.js:

```
router.route('/register')
    .post(function(req, res) {
         //register the user
    })
```

users.js:

```
router.route('/:user_id')
    //GET user profile
    .get(function(req, res){
        // Use the req.params.userId to get the user by Id
    })
```

*And this works well for these 2 both. Accessing `/api/auth/register` or `/api/users/:user_id` works as expected.*

But when trying to go for `/api/{world_id}/villages` this doesn't go as expected because the `world_id` parameter does not get passed to the file processing it which is villages.js

villages.js:

```
router.route('/')
    //GET all villages of the current world (world_id)
    .get(function(req, res){
        // Use the req.params.world_id to get it... but this is undefined :(
    })
```

**How can I have this file structure so my controllers don't get messy and at the same time, pass this parameter to the controller file so that it can use it even if the route is ('/')?**

Comment: does route `/:world_id/villages` doesn't fits you'r needs ?
But if you want to pass a variable you should wrap you'r content with a function and call it with parameter: `app.use(require('./some_dinamyc_routes')('world_id_1'));` But that's a bad practice..

Comment: @Maikal the route fits just fine. But the argument `:world_id` doesn't get passed to my villages.js file that handles the logic of returning the villages.

Comment: Sorry, completely not understood your problem..

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2138
This is intentianal behavior. Child router's cannot see parent's params..
Also this: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make any parameter visible inside the child router is to define it there.
So in you'r example

```
router.route('/:world_id/villages/')
    //GET all villages of the current world (world_id)
    .get(function(req, res){
        // req.params.world_id is set
    })
// ...
app.use('/', router);
```